# Select name for authors that havent written a book

Tags: sql

We have to select authors that havent written a book but there are 3 different tables which makes me confused about how to write the join expression.

We have tables:

```
authors: author_id
authorships: author_id, book_id
books: book_id.
```

Obviously I selected the names from authors and tried inner join but it wont work for me. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm trying to parse the statement:  How can an *author* not have written a book?  By what claim is the person an author?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good spot to use the `LEFT JOIN` antipattern:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM authors a
LEFT JOIN authorships s ON s.author_id = a.author_id
WHERE s.author_id IS NULL
```

Rationale: when the `LEFT JOIN` comes up empty, it means that the author has no corresponding record in the `authorships` table. The `WHERE` clause filters out on unmatched `authors` records only (ie authors that have no books). This is called an *antipattern* because the purpose of a `JOIN` is usually to match records, whereas here we use it to detect unmatched records.

Comment: Why antipattern?

Answer (score 0):

Since this sounds like a school assignment I won't give the full answer.

Try using an outer join between authors and authorship. Make sure you retrieve the book I'd from the authorship.

Try to work out what an author who has not published looks like the. You can use this to formulate the query for the answer you are looking for with an appropriate where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Its really easy, just check which column seems to be having common value between all this three tables if something is common atleast within two tables then put inner join on those two and an outer join on the uncommon data table.

Remember your Aliases will always matter when you join between different tables, also the ON and WHERE should be properly mentioned.